# Ruby: Read single file from tarball

Tags: ruby, tar, gzip

I want to read the contents of a single file from a .tar.gz tarball. The file is in the root of the tarball. Is there some easy way to do this? I was thinking about something like `data = Tarball.open('myfile.tar.gz').entry('/myentry').content` Is there such a thing?

Comment: Check out [TarReader](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Package/TarReader/Entry.html)

Comment: I did see that, but didn't really find out how to use it, will check it out though

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `.tar.gz` is not a structured file; it's just a `.tar` file that has been run through a compression algorithm that knows nothing about `tar`.  So the only way to get data back out of it is to uncompress the whole thing first.

As a less-space-efficient but more time-efficient alternative, you may want to consider exploding the tar file, recompressing each file individually, and then tarring them back up into an (uncompressed) archive.  Then extracting individual files is easy using the `archive-tar` gem, and you can just add a decompression step to recover the originals.

Comment: The issue is: i have a tarball made by another application and i want to extract metadata which is stored in a single file inside of it - as quickly as possible, as i do batch processing

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question without an answer accepted, so I wonder if it's still actual however, someone might come to it when running into a similar issue. If you know a typical pattern in the file you are looking for, you might be able to use

`tar xf yourarchive.tar.gz --wildcards 'yourpattern'`

, which would extract only the selected file and then you can use it as you prefer.
Let's say each tarball is expected to have an "app.conf" file then you use this in 'yourpattern'.

I hope this helps?